# signalr .net core , cors issue with angular 9

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, angular9

I am using SignalR in .net core 3.1 with angular 9. it's providing error.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/chathub/negotiate' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I am going to share my startup where I have configured SignalR and also providing a hub that is created on .net core.
I am also providing a client-side connection code that is written in angular 9.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
         app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
          app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
        });
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }
}
```

This is my Hub.

```
public class ChatHub: Hub
{
    public static List<UserModel> userModel = new List<UserModel>();

    
    public async Task SendMessage(UserModel model)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", model);
    }
}
```

And this is my client-side code that is written in angular

```
export class StartComponent implements OnInit {

public _apiservice : ApiServiceService;
private _hubConnection: HubConnection; 
constructor(apiservice : ApiServiceService) {
  this._apiservice = apiservice;
  this.createConnection();  
  this.startConnection();  

}

 register(){
   this._apiservice.registerUser();
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  private startConnection(): void {  

    this._hubConnection  
    .start()  
    .then(() => {  
    console.log('Hub connection started');   
   })  
  .catch(err => {  
    console.log('Error while establishing connection, retrying...');  
    // setTimeout(function () { this.startConnection(); }, 5000);  
    });  
  } 
  private createConnection() {  
         this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()  
         .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/" + 'chathub')  
         .build();  
            console.log('hub connection')
   }  

 }
```

I am working on a local computer. my angular app is running on the http://localhost:4200/ and dot net core application is running on http://localhost:5000/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked origin ASP.NET CORE 2.2.0 / Angular 8 / signalr1.0.0 \[(CORS Policy-Access-Control-Allow-Origin) failed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468525/access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-origin-asp-net-core-2-2-0-angular-8)

Comment: Thanks for response but this link does not solve this problem. kindly suggest.

Comment: in Dotnet core 3.1  Signlar replaced by 
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
        });
So kindly suggest what is the problem.

Comment: When I call API it's working fine but Signalr is not working.

Comment: But you configured CORS like my answer on that question?

Comment: Yes, I configured the same but the same problem. i used
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
                }));
in my service.

Comment: I also tried configuration like 
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
            });

but still not working.

Comment: app.UseCors need to be put between `app.UseRouting();` and `app.UseAuthorization();`You can see `Calls the UseCors extension method and specifies the _myAllowSpecificOrigins CORS policy. UseCors adds the CORS middleware. The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization.` in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware).