# How to allow cors with signalr

Tags: c#, api, iis, cors, signalr

Working on an app with signalr, managed to solve the cors error with the connection to the API but when trying to connecto to the hub it shows the error below which won't happen when debugging on my local computer even with different port.

> Access to fetch at 'http://iisServer:10079/fareg/signalr/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://iisServer' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here is my configuration on the app

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSignalR();//.AddMessagePackProtocol();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        //add Windows authentication for http options request
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddDbContext<FAContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FADB")));


        
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(options =>
        {
            //options.WithOrigins("http://schi-iis1zsus", "http://localhost:4200");
            options.AllowAnyOrigin();
            options.AllowAnyMethod();
            options.AllowAnyHeader();
            options.AllowCredentials();
        });

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<Hubs.HubFA>("/signalr");
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();



        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Please help, I've looking every where but haven't get a solution to this issue.

Comment: Did you install CORS module on IIS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468525/access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-origin-asp-net-core-2-2-0-angular-8/59487002#59487002

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked origin ASP.NET CORE 2.2.0 / Angular 8 / signalr1.0.0 \[(CORS Policy-Access-Control-Allow-Origin) failed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468525/access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-origin-asp-net-core-2-2-0-angular-8)

Comment: how do you install the CORS module on the IIS?

Comment: Refer to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference) and it has download link.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cross-origin-resource-sharing

You either need to specify the origins explicitly, or remove `AllowCredentials()` and set `withCredentials` to false on the client https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=javascript#configure-additional-options-1